# laravel valet Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused"

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-valet

im new in laravel-valet

valet has been installed in my windows. and everything is fine and work properly.
but unfortunately, i can't run my project suddenly. i can't even ping my project.
nothing happen in my valet path and my valet domain. all my project just can't run.

this is the issue

[image]

finally i tried to check the valet  share and got this
"Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4040: Connection refused"

please anyone help me to fix this issue
thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
valet domain test
```

Then visit myproject.test

The reason is that the `.dev` domain is now a TLD.

Comment: i tried "valet domain test". and this is the result : Pinging myproject.test [36.86.63.182] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out. wht should I do now Mr. Stoater?